# Imports recognized in Eclipse PyDev, but not in terminal

Tags: python, eclipse, import

Usually, people have problems with Eclipse PyDev recognizing certain imports, but I now encounter it the other way around. I have a directory `Sandbox` (which I made a namespace by adding an empty `__init__.py` in it). I have a class called `ffc` in module `ffc.py` in this directory, and a script `ff.py` in it.

ffc.py:

```
class ffc(object):
    def print_me(self):
        print 'The class fcc has been called'
```

ff.py:

```
from Sandbox.ffc import ffc
if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = ffc()
    f.print_me()
```

This script works in Eclipse PyDev (with F9), but not as a script in the terminal:

From the directory `Sandbox`:

```
Sandbox david$ python ff.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ff.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Sandbox.ffc import ffc
ImportError: No module named Sandbox.ffc
```

From the parent directory of the directory `Sandbox`:

```
$ python Sandbox/ff.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sandbox/ff.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Sandbox.ffc import ffc
ImportError: No module named Sandbox.ffc
```

What do I need to do to make this import work? Can it be done without adding it to `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Is `Sandbox` in the directory you're running the interpreter from or in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: It is in the directory I run the script from. To be clear, I run: `python Sandbox/ff.py`. The directory is not in the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: That is not what your post states. In your post you run `python ff.py` rather than `python Sandbox/ff.py`. Since `Sandbox` is not your `PYTHONPATH` the former wouldn't work. Are you sure you're running the latter?

Comment: I updated the post. I tried both methods, they are now in the OP. Could it be that the import-line is starting to look from the directory the script is located in?

Comment: Definitely. If you have a subdirectory called `Sandbox` inside `Sandbox` it will try importing from that subdirectory since `sys.path[0]` is the empty string, denoting the current directory.

Comment: Then it is clear to me why this fails. Would it be a good idea to point to all directories then with relative paths from where the current module is situated? If not, what would be the best way to import all relevant modules?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think that would be acceptable. Your two options are either absolute imports or explicit relative imports, and that's a matter a taste. Google a bit to learn more on this issue. There are a lot of related questions and some interesting articles on the subject.